# MySQL Trigger Before Update New vs Old

Tags: mysql, triggers

I need help adjusting a before update trigger to recognize when the previous value changes, including from NULL and BLANK.

```
If NEW.column_1 <> OLD.column_1 then…….
```

I think I can use <=> to check if the previous value was NULL but what about when it changes from blank?

Travis

Comment: How about `If not NEW.column_1 = OLD.column_1 then ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<=>` operator does test if a blank value is equal to a non-blank value.

```
mysql> select '' <=> 'notblank' as same;
+------+
| same |
+------+
|    0 |
+------+
```